# Setting the same style for multiple nested elements

Tags: html, css

Okay, I have the following CSS:

```
.gridViewStyle tr th, .gridViewStyle tr td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

And it's working as expected and applying the padding to both the `th` and `td` elements. **However, do I really have to declare the fully qualified path multiple times?** Or in other words, **is there a more concise way of doing the same thing?**

### UPDATE

**SPECIFICITY**

In regards to specificity, I cannot have this applied to other tables, it must strictly be applied to the grid view with this CSS class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on specificity, you don't need anything more than `th {` or `td {`.

It just depends if you have another table or not. `th, td {` would be the shortest way if you don't. If you do, that `tr` is doing nothing (as all `th` and `td` should be inside a row, so remove it)

Comment: Please see my update for clarity, please accept my apologies.

Comment: Then the shortest CSS you can do is `.gridViewStyle th, .gridViewStyle td`, .gridViewStyle tells it to only use this specific table, and then you are picking the elements you want. `tr` is a bit pointless. Alternatively, add a class to the tr and th elements and use that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `tr`. As both `td` and `th` elements will fall within the `tr`, it is reduntant, as a space selects all descendants (not just children). Therefore,

```
.gridViewStyle th, .gridViewStyle td {
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also do it something like this, will be respecting your specificity too, this is the shortest way you can achieve it

```
.gridViewStyle th, .gridViewStyle td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not in CSS only though.

There's still CSS preprocessors LESS or SASS which will allow you to do this :

```
.gridViewStyle tr 
{
    th, td { padding: 5px; }

}
```

If you are interested, here are a few links

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: So to define it as you have shown I would need to *include* the less CSS JS file right?

Comment: Yes but as the LESS website says, it's ok to use those 2 files to get started, but don't use the CSS and JS files for production. For a live website you should definitely compile your css. Useful tools for compiling: http://wearekiss.com/simpless and http://winless.org/online-less-compiler